# ajax call success but no data returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to parse a jQuery initialized array to PHP with an AJAX POST. However, I am trying to alert the `ToString()` of an array. Here is my ajax call, I am essentially trying to just take an array and pass it to my PHP for some further manipulation. Here is my code:

```
   AllArray.push("Alim");
   AllArray.push("Jonathon");
   AllArray.push("Kyle");
   var returnVal = AllArray.toString();
   $.ajax({        
   type: "POST",
   data: { 'allInfoArray' : returnVal },
   success: function() {
        console.log("AJAX Fired");  
   }
```

This is the PHP in my html file. I am trying to alert the array for debug purposes.

```
 $allTeamArray = $_GET['allInfoArray'];
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$allTeamArray');</script>";
```

Comment: adding to @FuzzyTree's answer: the alert you are trying won't work as expected, because you are not redirecting to the page (hence not displaying/interpreting it), but only recieving it's output as parameter of `success`-function

Comment: Weird because the function logs to the console, and redirects to the correct page. The alert box comes up but nothing is displayed, I changed _REQUEST to _POST as well...

Comment: it redirects to what page when? there is no url defined in ajax!? An ajax call should not redirect somewhere.... Are these two seperate files??

Comment: This code is triggered from inside  `$("#myForm").submit(function()`

Comment: can you show the complete code?

Answer (score 3):

Your ajax call passes the value via `POST` but you're alerting `GET`, which is why your alert isn't displaying the expected data.

```
$allTeamArray = $_GET['allInfoArray'];
                ^ change to $_POST
```